# Python pass condition formatting a dictionary

Tags: python, if-statement

I am formatting a dictionary like so:

```
for index, team_id in dataframe.get('team_id').items():
    format_redis[str(team_id)] = {
                'x': float(dataframe['x'][index]),
                'y': float(dataframe['y'][index]),
                'z': float(dataframe['z'][index]),
                'n': float(dataframe['n'][index])
            }
```

Now I'd like to pass a condition for adding the value, like:
...

```
 {'x': float(dataframe['x'][index]) if str(dataframe['home'][index] == 'home',
 'y': float(dataframe['y'][index]) if str(dataframe['home'][index] == 'away'}
```

---

But this syntax is not valid. Which one is the right one?

Comment: Your example is missing closing `)`

Comment: You must have the `else` part in the `if-else` operator,